# Call Javascript function in Codebehind from Button click event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to call the 'Onclientclick' in a buttonclick event after a condition is checked .However it is not working .Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

```
<asp:Button ID="but_Submit" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClientClick="$('#Section8_tab').trigger('click')" ValidationGroup="ADD" CssClass="w3-btn w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-hover-red"
                                            OnClick="but_Submit_Click" TabIndex="23">
```

Comment: The form submits with the button click then the server button handler code runs and finally a new version of the page is sent in the response to the browser. At that point any scripts registered on startup run like normal. There is no 'state' here to tell the page to run the javascript event again. I'd restructure the button click code to be an ajax callable webmethod and evoke it from the client side button handler code but there other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<asp:Button ID="but_Submit" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClientClick="return $('#Section8_tab').trigger('click')" ValidationGroup="ADD" CssClass="w3-btn w3-blue w3-padding-large w3-hover-red"
                                        OnClick="but_Submit_Click" TabIndex="23">
```